# Allow login only from a specified PC

Tags: asp.net, security

We are developing an ASP.NET Web Forms application and we need to allow users to login, only from their own PCs.

We have been thinking about this for a few days and we have come up with these solutions:

1. When defining a user, specify the IP address from which he can login, and later, check if the request IP matches the one specified for the user. (The user can change his IP very easily. We cam limit the user, so he is unable to change his IP, but again, this is not 100% secure).
2. Use ActiveX and get the clients MAC address and check if the username is allowed to login from that MAC address. (This is not a good choice since we want to avoid ActiveX).

We want to go with the first solution. I know there is no 100% secure solution, but I wonder if there are any better solutions than these two.

Comment: Can you use kerberos in some fashion, like FreeIPA does?

Answer (score -1):

ActiveX will not work on client machine or no any hack is there to get client machine details better and safe solution is IP address and if you wanna extend security then you can create service(exe file) that will run by client to identify himself :)

Comment: IP's change and can be spoofed, this is not a reliable way to identify someone. Not to mention computers on a single network will report the same public IP.